# Apache restart failed

Tags: apache2, ssl

I was adding a new certificate in letsencrpt's certbot and when i restart apache2, this happened.

> sudo apache2ctl configtest

**Output:**

```
    apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 14 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/in.morphing.myop-le-ssl.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: And the file is there with adequate access flags?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some similar issues. I updated to Raspbian Stretch and the issues started. When using certbot-auto -renew the virtual environment could not be created. I started uninstalling and reinstalling all kinds off stuff and kept un running into errors. Eventually I uncommented the configuration in  /etc/network/interfaces because this needs to be in /etc/dhcpcd.conf otherwise the network interface gets an error and the dhcpcd service won't start correctly.

After that I was able to renew the certificates but ran into your issue. I think in the installing and reinstalling the files where removed. So I copied the config file from the Apache2 folder:

```
cp /etc/letsencrypt/certbot-ci/certbot_integration_tests/assets/sample-config/options-ssl-apache.conf /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

Then I disabled SSL and disabled the redirects in the default conf in sites-enabled folder. (My site redirected to different ports and addresses, not sure if this is applicable for you).

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then the service was able to start and I was able to renew the certificates. I then made sure the certificates where moved to the correct locations and the config file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf contained the correct paths to the certificates. (I had mydomain-001.nl/fullchain.pem while in the new configuration it is mydomain.nl/fullchain.pem.

Enabled SSL again:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And finally it worked again :) I'm no expert but I hope this helps you figure it out. Feel free to ask any additional questions.